# Text classifying with homograph words

Tags: nlp, similarity, text-classification

I have a dataset to classify some categories. In some samples, some words are called homographs.

> Homograph: Sets of words that have the same spelling but different
> meanings regardless of the fact whether they are pronounced the same
> or not. (letter, bat, install, etc.)

For example "install";

> The first meaning is "to put software onto a computer"
>
> The second meaning is "to put a piece of equipment somewhere"

I tried to find similarities between two samples that include "install" in this usage. The score is very high with spacy.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc1 = nlp('SSD installed.')
doc2 = nlp('Windows installed.')
doc2.similarity(doc1)
```

I want to distinguish these sentences. How can I solve this problem? which models I can use?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, I'll encourage you to ask the question here in the discussion instead https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions. Most probably the questions would be flagged as "asking for tool/fix recommendation" as it is now.